# Match vector values with elements in list in R

Tags: r, sapply

I am trying to match a vector of months to the appropriate quarter in R. Unfortunately, the code I inherited contains the quarters in a list with the appropriate months as a vector of each list element (this least is supposed to be adaptable such that you could do quarters, trimesters, or semesters if desired). Currently, I am using `sapply` to loop through the vector and match the appropriate quarter to each month as follows:

```
month.vec <- sample(1:12, 100, replace=T)
quarters.list <- list(`1` = 1:3, `2` = 4:6, `3` = 7:9, `4` = 10:12)

month.to.quarter <- function(months, quarters) {
    sapply(months, FUN=function(x) {
        as.numeric(substr(names(which(x == unlist(quarters))),0,1))
    })
}
month.to.quarter(month.vec, quarters.list)
```

This works great for vectors of about `length(month.vec) < 1e5` or so, but is a bit time consuming after that (see code below). Does anyone have an elegant solution for this sort of matching at vectors longer than this?

Script to show how processing time increases with vector length. NOTE: this takes a few seconds (<10)

```
times <- NULL
for (i in c(10 %o% 10^(2:5))) {
    month.vec <- sample(1:12, i, replace=T)
    quarters.list <- list(`1` = 1:3, `2` = 4:6, `3` = 7:9, `4` = 10:12)
    t <- system.time(a <- month.to.quarter(month.vec, quarters.list))[3]
    time <- data.frame(n = i, time = t)
    times <- rbind(times, time)
}
plot(time ~ n, times)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder whether it would be faster to invert the quarters list, so that the quarter can just be looked up using month as the index.  Something like the following...

```
quarters <- as.numeric(substr(names(sort(unlist(quarters.list))),1,1))
```

This only needs to be done once, and then you can just do

```
quarters.vec <- quarters[month.vec]
```

It is about 2000 times faster...

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(quarters[month.vec],month.to.quarter(month.vec, quarters.list))
Unit: microseconds
                                       expr        min         lq        mean     median          uq        max neval
                        quarters[month.vec]    199.836    202.629    235.3968    227.763    233.9695    554.823   100
 month.to.quarter(month.vec, quarters.list) 439466.006 456649.059 495957.5722 469543.098 499346.5020 935046.664   100
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. I love elegant solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(month.vec - 1) %/% 3 + 1
```

Comment: This works as well, but I like the above answer by Andrew Gustar as it can be implemented to any time grouping other than quarters (e.g. bi-annually, trimesters, or any bizarre grouping of months you can think of).

Answer (score 0):

This is the first method I came up with. I think I saw it in Hudley's book. It uses names for the element of a vector.

```
month.vec <- sample(1:12, 10000, replace=T)
quarters.list <- list(`1` = 1:3, `2` = 4:6, `3` = 7:9, `4` = 10:12)
# your method
month.to.quarter <- function(months, quarters) {
  sapply(months, FUN=function(x) {
    as.numeric(substr(names(which(x == unlist(quarters))),0,1))
  })
}
out1 <-month.to.quarter(month.vec, quarters.list)

# my method
vec <- rep(1:4, each = 3)
names(vec) <- 1:12
out2 <- vec[month.vec]
names(out2) <- NULL
all.equal(out1, out2) # this will return TRUE
```

Benchmark is really different.

```
month.vec <- sample(1:12, 10000, replace=T)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(vec[month.vec],
month.to.quarter(month.vec, quarters.list))

## Unit: microseconds
##                                       expr       min        lq       mean    median        uq        max neval
##                             vec[month.vec]   108.503   112.433   119.3982   116.916   119.983    183.467   100
## month.to.quarter(month.vec, quarters.list) 78859.160 84036.995 87956.6532 86960.269 89975.668 140797.487   100
```

The new method is about 800 times faster.

If you want to make it a function it's like this and still quite fast

```
month.to.quarter2 <- function(months) {
  vec <- rep(1:4, each = 3)
  names(vec) <- 1:12
  out <- vec[months]
  names(out) <- NULL
  return(out)
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(vec[month.vec],
                               month.to.quarter(month.vec, quarters.list),
                               month.to.quarter2(month.vec))

## Unit: microseconds
##                                        expr       min         lq       mean    median        uq        max neval
##                              vec[month.vec]   109.222   111.6345   121.3035   115.604   117.916    706.034   100
##  month.to.quarter(month.vec, quarters.list) 77292.742 83032.7425 85770.6963 84690.500 87243.327 138531.309   100
##                month.to.quarter2(month.vec)   117.264   120.3555   127.6535   127.021   133.474    153.556   100
```